# SQL query to return nested array of objects in JSON for SQLite

Tags: sql, node.js, json, sqlite, express

I have 2 simple tables in a SQLite db and a nodejs, express api endpoint that should get results by student and have the subjects as a nested array of objects.

Tables:
Student(id, name) and Subject(id, name, studentId)

This is what I need to result to look like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Student name",
    "subjects": 
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Subject 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Subject 2"
    }]
}
```

How can I write a query to get this result?

Answer (score 3):

If your version of sqlite was built with support for the [JSON1](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) extension, it's easy to generate the JSON from the query itself:

```
SELECT json_object('id', id, 'name', name
                 , 'subjects'
                 , (SELECT json_group_array(json_object('id', subj.id, 'name', subj.name))
                    FROM subject AS subj
                    WHERE subj.studentid = stu.id)) AS record
FROM student AS stu
WHERE id = 1;
```

```
record
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"id":1,"name":"Student Name","subjects":[{"id":1,"name":"Subject 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Subject 2"}]}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get record as pure json object not json string? I am getting response in json string

Comment: @DrashtiKheni You'd have to use your language's facilities for parsing a string holding JSON data and converting it to a native data structure.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that all you need is a `LEFT JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT subject.id, subject.name, student.id, student.name 
FROM subject 
LEFT JOIN student ON subject.studentId = student.id
ORDER BY student.id;
```

Then just parse the rows of the response into the object structure you require.